# Error in sending mail through PHP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Here is a sample code to send email using PHPMailer

```
<? require('./PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$body = 'This is the message';

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;

$mail->Username   = 'tanishq@gmail.com';
$mail->Password   = 'xyz';

$mail->SetFrom('tanishq@gmail.com', $name);
$mail->Subject    = 'subject';
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAddress('rohit@gmail.com', 'title1');
$mail->AddAddress('mark@gmail.com', 'title2'); 


$mail->send();
?>
```

[UPDATED]
and I am getting this weird error

> 2017-05-08 14:37:36   SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2017-05-08 14:37:36    SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

P.S- I have also tried most of the solutions given on this site however am not getting success through that so i would appreciate if you can help me

Comment: make sure error reporting displays NOTICEs, too. if you had done this you would have caught this immediately.

Comment: very true @JohnConde. The number one method of debugging

Comment: are short tags enabled?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yup they are

Comment: There are some obvious issues with your code that are explicitly covered in the troubleshooting guide that the "weird error" links you to. Follow it and do what it says. It looks like you've based your code on an obsolete example, so make sure you're using the latest versions of everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

should be

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

I think?

Comment: Oops sorry for that , I have updated it, but still am getting this error

Comment: Maybe try port 465?